# Does Pervasive 13 Offer Triggers, or some similar Alternative?

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql

Does [Pervasive 13](https://docs.actian.com/psql/PSQLv13/) offer any mechanism by which actions can be initiated each time a row is added to a particular table, and each time a row is modified in a particular table?

Other databases call these "triggers", and they're a crucial mechanism for event-driven development that avoids inefficient polling techniques.

Comment: Found [this](https://docs.actian.com/psql/PSQLv13/#page/prog_gde%2FSqlstore.htm%23ww10047).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found, Triggers are available in Pervasive 13. But there is a caveat on triggers.  If your application only uses the SQL interfaces (ODBC, OLEDB, JBC, PDAC - TPvSqlSession, TPvQuery, etc) then your application will be fine.  If you use any Btrieve / transactional interface then your application may stop working correctly.

Once a trigger is set on a Pervasive file, Btrieve access for that operation is disabled.  For example if you create an Insert Trigger, then Btrieve Inserts will return a status 149 and the operation will fail.  Same is true of Update and Delete triggers.

Comment: You're right. I tried to implement a trigger last night, as a means of maintaining a synchronization with an external system. I created a log_table, and the trigger was set to log all inserts, updates, and deletes (of a particular table) to that log_table, which I could poll frequently and efficiently to tell what needs to get synced externally. Unfortunately, our ERP is using Btrieve. So while the trigger worked, during my own SQL inserts and updates, it broke the ERP to where it couldn't even add an order to that table without error 149 crashing it.

Comment: Too me, it seems theoretically possible to make triggers work on all database access methods. Without triggers working on Btrieve also, I'm having to resort to way less efficient ways of detecting table modifications. If the ERP's database design reliably updated a timestamp for each update, I'd still be ok, but I can't depend on that in the case (believe me).

Comment: Do you know of some Btrieve methodology where I can detect additions and modifications to a table? Is there some other log somewhere, where I could access that instead and potentially accomplish the same thing as the trigger + log_table failed solution?

Comment: Currently (Actian Zen v15 and going back to Btrieve 6.15 / Scalable SQL 3.0) there is no way for Triggers to work the way you want.  I'm also not aware of any Btrieve methodology for detecting additions or modifications.